# Is a dictionary patch the appropriate term used to describe an acronym?

Tags: oop, object, dictionary

In Silicon Valley S03E01 Gilfoyle and Dinesh have a conversation about Richard. In the conversation they use the term dictionary patch as such:

> Gilfoyle: What if we use like a dictionary patch? To compress all the
>   nice-guy stuff. 
>   Dinesh: Like an acronym. 
>   Gilfoyle: Exactly. "Richard is great, but you know"... R-I-G-B-Y. 
>   Dinesh: Rigby. 
>   Gilfoyle: Rigby is all the nice-guy stuff.

Wouldn't that be a dictionary key?

Example of a dictionary key:

```
var dictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dictionary["RIGBY"] = "Richard is great, but you know";
console.log(dictionary["RIGBY"]); 
// output is "Richard is great, but you know";
```

in this case the dictionary key is "RIGBY"

http://siliconvalleyism.com/silicon-valley-quote.php?id=135

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just plain not even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of the term "dictionary patch" outside of Silicon Valley. But, yes, `'RIGBY'` would be the *dictionary key*, but *dictionary patch* wasn't just talking about the *key*. They were referring to a process of using a dictionary key to replace a long value with that key. So, he's calling this whole higher-level process "dictionary patching", although I've never heard of it.